How can I use my javascript code inside of my page.jsx?
So I want use this code (.js file):
It is just a static javascript code
const { exportTraceState } = require("next/dist/trace");

const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.toggle_btn')
 const toggleBtnIcon = document.querySelector('.toggle_btn')
 const dropDownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown_menu')
 

     toggleBtn.onclick = function(){
          dropDownMenu.classList.toggle('open')
          const isOpen = dropDownMenu.classList.contains('open')

          toggleBtnIcon.classList = isOpen
          ? 'fa-solid fa-xmark'
          : 'fa-solid fa-bars'
      }

in this code (.jsx file):
Where can I use the javascript code or how can I implement it?
Because <script> does not work either and the code needs to be a in a server state because of the next auth.
import Image from "next/image";
import Head from "next/head";
import Script from "next/script";
import { UserButton, auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
 const {userId } = auth();
 console.log(userId);
 
 return (
     <>
     <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
     <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
     <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
     <div className="body">
          <nav>
               <div className="navbar">
                    <div className="logo"><a href="#">TradeProject</a></div>
               
               <ul className="links">
                    <li><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
               </ul>
               <a href="/sign-up" className="action_btn">Get Started</a>
               <div className="toggle_btn">
               <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
               </div>
               </div>
               <div className="dropdown_menu">
               <li><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/sign-up" className="action_btn">Get Started</a></li>
               </div>
          </nav>
     </div>

   </>
 );
}

That both code work together without any errors

Using code that directly attaches to and manipulates the DOM inside React is generally a bad idea, you would be much better off doing this using React state and attaching event listeners directly to the JSX components.

For toggleBtnIcon, I think you forget to add i in the selector after .toggle_btn to target the icon, it should look like
 const toggleBtnIcon = document.querySelector('.toggle_btn i')

First, you hook the click even in the JSX by onClick, then you make a state for the open flag, which toggles when .toggle_btn clicked, and conditionally add the class for the icon like className={isOpen ? "fa-solid fa-xmark" : "fa-solid fa-bars"}
This is a full example of code.
import Image from "next/image";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { UserButton, auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
 const {userId } = auth();
 const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

 const toggleDropdown = () => {
   setIsOpen(!isOpen);
 };

 console.log(userId);
 
 return (
     <>
     <Head>
       <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
       <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
       <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
     </Head>
     <div className="body">
          <nav>
               <div className="navbar">
                    <div className="logo"><a href="#">TradeProject</a></div>
               
               <ul className="links">
                    <li><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#features">Features</
<>
     <Head>
       <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
       <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
       <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
     </Head>
     <div className="body">
          <nav>
               <div className="navbar">
                    <div className="logo"><a href="#">TradeProject</a></div>
               
               <ul className="links">
                    <li><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
               </ul>
               <a href="/sign-up" className="action_btn">Get Started</a>
               <div className="toggle_btn" onClick={toggleDropdown}>
                   <i className={isOpen ? "fa-solid fa-xmark" : "fa-solid fa-bars"}></i>
               </div>
               </div>
               <div className={`dropdown_menu ${isOpen ? 'open' : ''}`}>
                    <li><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/sign-up" className="action_btn">Get Started</a></li>
               </div>
          </nav>
     </div>
   </>
 );
}


getting this errror: Error:
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\suhaa\OneDrive\Desktop\TradeProject\tradeproject.next\fallback-build-manifest.json'
